# Como recuperar os dados vindos do model?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Estou usando roteamento com [DRouter](http://drouter.downsmaster.com) e sempre preciso pegar os dados de tal loja pelo *slug*, para isso preciso fazer 1 `select` em todas as rotas.

Mas não sei como pegar o *id*, *nome* e *slug* vindos lá do *SistemaModel.php* e por ali na *index.php* usando a variável `$dados`.

Diz que a variável `$dados` que não existe e que não é um objeto.

*index.php*

```
$app = new DRouter\App();
$app->render->setViewsFolder(__DIR__.'/App/Views/');
require 'App/Controllers/SistemaController.php';

/* Login */
$app->get('/:slug/admin', function($slug){
    SistemaController::dadosLoja($slug);
    $this->render->load('lojista/loj_login.php', [
        'id_loja' => $dados->id,
        'nome_loja' => $dados->nome,
        'slug_loja' => $dados->slug
    ]);
});
```

*SistemaController.php*

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Models/SistemaModel.php';
class SistemaController
{
    public static function dadosLoja($slug){
        $dados = SistemaModel::slug($slug);
        if($dados != false){
            return $dados;
        }
    }
}
```

*SistemaModel.php*

```
class SistemaModel
{
    public static function slug($slug){
        $dados = DB::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `admin_lojas` WHERE `slug` = :slug");
        $dados->bindValue(':slug', $slug, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $dados->execute();
        if(count($dados) == 1){
            return $dados;
        }
    }
}
```

*DB.php*

```
class DB
{
    private static $conn;
    public function __construct(){}

    public static function conn(){
        try {
            if(is_null(self::$conn)){
                self::$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.BD.'',''.USER.'',''.PASS.'',
                array(
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
                ));
            }
            return (self::$conn) ? self::$conn : false;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Está usando composer-autoloader? Realmente é necessário usar `require`? Quero dizer se usa composer-autoloader não seria mais facil configurar os namespaces no composer.json? Posta a classe `DB::conn`, não tem como saber se é um framework ou se foi vc quem criou.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento estou usando o DRouter para roteamento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso está errado:

```
if(count($dados) == 1){
    return $dados;
}
```

O `$dados` é um [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php), posso estar enganado, mas ele só itera com um `foreach`, ele não conta os resultados, para isso você deve fazer isso:

```
$dados->execute();

$count = $dados->rowCount();

if($dados > 0){
```

Claro que se eu entendi o seu código, agora isso também me parece errado:

```
    return $dados;
```

Você está retornando o objeto e não os dados, para isso é necessário [`$dados->fetchAll();`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) (retorna multiplas linhas)

Deve ficar tudo assim:

```
class SistemaModel
{
    public static function slug($slug){
        $dados = DB::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `admin_lojas` WHERE `slug` = :slug");
        $dados->bindValue(':slug', $slug, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $dados->execute();

        if($dados->rowCount() > 0){
            return $dados->fetchAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Se slug retorna apenas um item, então acredito que o correto seria [`$dados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

```
class SistemaModel
{
    public static function slug($slug){
        $dados = DB::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `admin_lojas` WHERE `slug` = :slug");
        $dados->bindValue(':slug', $slug, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $dados->execute();

        if($dados->rowCount() > 0){
            return $dados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }
}
```

### Documentação

É altamente recomendável que leia a documentação e evite escrever códigos aleatoriamente sem saber o que cada função faz, links:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php